# How to scan buffer, which is defines in structure, correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, structure, fgets

This is my structure:

```
struct Data{
   char *buffer[MAXBUFF];
   int bufferSize;
};
```

This is how I call my function searchInFile:

```
searchInFile(logFile, outFile, &dat);
```

This is searchInFile function itself:

```
void searchInFile(FILE *logFile, FILE *outFile, struct Data *dat){
   FILE *srcFile = fopen("src.txt", "r");

   if(!srcFile){
      printf("Nepavyko atidaryti \"src.txt\" failo.\n");
      fprintf(logFile, "Nepavyko atidaryti \"src.txt\" failo.\n");
      fclose(srcFile);
      return;
   } else {
      fprintf(logFile, "Failas \"src.txt\" atidarytas sekmingai.\n");
   }

   while(!feof(srcFile)){
      fgets((*dat).buffer, MAXBUFF, srcFile);
      printf("%s", dat->buffer);
   }

   fclose(srcFile);
}
```

What I am trying to do is scan chars to a buffer, which is defined in structure. I get warning, which says that I pass argument of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type. How to scan it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `fgets` should be a `char *`.

So you  need to fix the structure definition from

```
struct Data{
   char *buffer[MAXBUFF];
   int bufferSize;
};
```

TO

```
struct Data{
   char buffer[MAXBUFF];
   int bufferSize;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the pointer from  `buffer`:

```
struct Data{
   char buffer[MAXBUFF];
   int bufferSize;
};
```